# How can pandas concat function duplicate behavior of append function in pandas,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I've just inherited some code that uses pandas' `append` method. This code causes Pandas to issue the following warning:

```
The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas 
in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

So, I want to use `pandas.concat`, without changing the behavior the `append` method gave. However, I can't.

Below I've recreated code that illustrates my problem. It creates an empty DataFrame with 31 columns and shape (0,31). When a new, empty row is appended to this DataFrame, the result has shape (1,31). In the code below, I've tried several ways to use `concat` and get the same behavior as `append`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create Empty Dataframe With Column Headings
obs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['basedatetime_before', 'lat_before', 'lon_before', 
                            'sog_before', 
                            'cog_before', 
                            'heading_before', 
                            'vesselname_before', 'imo_before', 
                            'callsign_before', 
                            'vesseltype_before', 'status_before', 
                            'length_before', 'width_before', 
                            'draft_before',
                            'cargo_before', 
                            'basedatetime_after', 'lat_after', 
                            'lon_after', 
                            'sog_after', 
                            'cog_after', 'heading_after', 
                            'vesselname_after', 'imo_after', 
                            'callsign_after', 
                            'vesseltype_after', 'status_after', 
                            'length_after', 'width_after', 
                            'draft_after', 
                            'cargo_after'])

# Put initial values in DataFrame
desired = pd.Timestamp('2016-03-20 00:05:00+0000', tz='UTC')
obs['point'] = desired
obs['basedatetime_before'] = pd.to_datetime(obs['basedatetime_before'])
obs['basedatetime_after'] = pd.to_datetime(obs['basedatetime_after'])
obs.rename(lambda s: s.lower(), axis = 1, inplace = True)

# Create new 'dummy' row
new_obs = pd.Series([desired], index=['point'])

# Get initial Shape Information
print("Orig obs.shape", obs.shape)
print("New_obs.shape", new_obs.shape)
print("--------------------------------------")

# Append new dummy row to Data Frame
obs1 = obs.append(new_obs, ignore_index=True)

# Attempt to duplicate effect of append with concat
obs2 = pd.concat([obs, new_obs])
obs3 = pd.concat([obs, new_obs], ignore_index=True)
obs4 = pd.concat([obs, new_obs.T])
obs5 = pd.concat([obs, new_obs.T], ignore_index=True)
obs6 = pd.concat([new_obs, obs])
obs7 = pd.concat([new_obs, obs], ignore_index=True)
obs8 = pd.concat([new_obs.T, obs])
obs9 = pd.concat([new_obs.T, obs], ignore_index=True)

# Verify original DataFrame hasn't changed and append still works 
obs10 = obs.append(new_obs, ignore_index=True)

# Print results
print("----> obs1.shape",obs1.shape)
print("obs2.shape",obs2.shape)
print("obs3.shape",obs3.shape)
print("obs4.shape",obs4.shape)
print("obs5.shape",obs5.shape)
print("obs6.shape",obs6.shape)
print("obs7.shape",obs7.shape)
print("obs8.shape",obs8.shape)
print("obs9.shape",obs9.shape)
print("----> obs10.shape",obs10.shape)
```

However, every way I've tried to use `concat` to add a new row to the DataFrame results in a new DataFrame with shape (1,32). This can be seen in the results shown below:

```
    Orig obs.shape (0, 31)
    New_obs.shape (1,)
    --------------------------------------
    ----> obs1.shape (1, 31)
    obs2.shape (1, 32)
    obs3.shape (1, 32)
    obs4.shape (1, 32)
    obs5.shape (1, 32)
    obs6.shape (1, 32)
    obs7.shape (1, 32)
    obs8.shape (1, 32)
    obs9.shape (1, 32)
    ----> obs10.shape (1, 31)
```

How can I use `concat` to add `new_obs` to the `obs` DataFrame and get a DataDrame with shape (1, 31) instead of (1,32)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_obs = pd.Series([desired], index=['point'])
new_obs=pd.DataFrame(new_obs)
new_obs.columns=['point']
```

In Series data type, it does not contain "column name". Therefore in your orginal code, it will append into a table below as a undifined table column name. PLease add a column name after converse it to dataframe type
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can first transform new_obs as a dataframe, and then use concat:

```
new_obs2 = pd.DataFrame(new_obs).transpose()
obs11 = pd.concat([obs, new_obs2])
print("obs11.shape",obs11.shape)
```

Output:

```
obs11.shape (1, 31)
```

But maybe there is a more direct way.